# Selenium WebDrive problems with foreach

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

So i try to do the foreach with the links i got but the code inside the foreach just work for the first link, ater this it dosen't work anymore and i got this error message.

```
    $links = $driver->findElements( WebDriverBy::xpath( '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentBody_grvStudentResult"]/tbody/tr/td/span/a' ) );
foreach( $links as $key => $value )
{
    $link = $value->getAttribute( 'href' );
    $rawPage = $driver->get( $link );

    $dados = $rawPage->findElement( WebDriverBy::cssSelector( '#fmvSession tbody tr td h2' ) )->getText();
    $a = explode( ': ', $dados );
    $b = explode( ', ', $a[ 1 ]);
    echo "01: " . trim( $b[ 0 ] ) . "\n";
    echo "02: " . trim( $b[ 1 ] )  . "\n";
}
```

Error Message:

> Fatal error: Uncaught
>   Facebook\WebDriver\Exception\StaleElementReferenceException: stale
>   element reference: element is not attached to the page document
>   (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.102)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are navigating to another page `$links` is not valid anymore, you are in a new page so the previously located WebElements are now stale. Save the links as list of strings and iterate over it

```
$elements = $driver->findElements(WebDriverBy::xpath( '//*[@id="ctl00_ContentBody_grvStudentResult"]/tbody/tr/td/span/a'));

$links = [];
foreach ($elements as $element) {
    $links[] = $element->getAttribute('href');
}

foreach($links as $link)
{
    $rawPage = $driver->get($link);
}
```